# shell script: Convert hard coded hyperlink to generic one

Tags: html, shell

I am having many html files, these are having href hardcoded thats why when I copy them from linux to windows server the hyper links don't work. I want to remove these hard coded full path. Below is an example, all the entries are masked.

```
<td align=center> <a href=http://example.com/jenkins/xyz_proj/job/XYZ_abc_item//ws/ABCD_122334/Report_ABCD/errorSummary_AB_type_2/error_abc.plugin.task123files_20181005_23476_234.out/*view*/ target=_blank> 0 </a> </td>
```

I want to remove the hyperlink so that it shows like below.

```
<td align=center> <a href=Report_ABCD/errorSummary_AB_type_2/error_abc.plugin.task123files_20181005_23476_234.out target=_blank> 0 </a> </td>
```

Please note that i have removed characters from both starting as well as end from the hyperlink.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to remove unwanted text from all the html files in current directory.

```
ls *.html | while read i in
do
sed -i 's/\(href=\).*\(Report\)/\1\2/' $i
sed -i 's/\/\*view\*\///g' $i
done
```